# Problems with multiple rows as result of a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a problem with this query :

```
SELECT tempo.* FROM tempo,fermata WHERE fermata.Via = '' 
      AND fermata.identificativo=(SELECT DISTINCT tempo.Nome_Fermata 
          FROM ( tempo
             INNER JOIN fermata ON fermata.identificativo = tempo.Nome_Fermata ))
```

PhpMyAdmin display me this error : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV5hZ.jpg)

Comment: and what's the problem?

Comment: obviously it will return multiple values from your distinct which would upset idenitificatvio=

Comment: Are you expecting a single row?  Perhaps you can share some information about the tables and data?

Answer (score 0):

multiple result from subquery due to '=' where it should be 'in' or use 'exists'

```
SELECT tempo.* FROM tempo,fermata WHERE fermata.Via = '' 
      AND fermata.identificativo in (SELECT DISTINCT tempo.Nome_Fermata 
          FROM  tempo
             INNER JOIN fermata ON fermata.identificativo = tempo.Nome_Fermata )
```

Comment: looks to me that the same tables are called in the subquery... wondering if the homework is to get the distinct rows rather than using a subquery